# Looping through filtered column cells: Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a table of data with headers going across the top and the left side. I am filtering each column, one at a time(starting at column 2). I want to assign a certain value(the header to the left) to an array for each of the rows still present after filtering. My code, however, does not pull from the filtered range, but the unfiltered range. Ex: my filtered range is rows 1,4,8,9 and excel pulls 1,2,3,4. Any ideas how I can modify my code?

```
constant = 0: i = 1: o = 1
Application.Visible = True
Set WS_Prods_With = Sheets.Add

For z = 3 To LstCol1 
RA_counter = 0: CP_counter = 0: counter = 0
ReDim ProdWith(1 To 1)
ProdWith(1) = "" 'Clearing out array
With WS_Sel
    If (.AutoFilterMode And .FilterMode) Or .FilterMode Then
    .ShowAllData 'Turning off previous filter
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(counter, LstCol1)).AutoFilter Field:=z, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Set rngFilter_Yes = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), _
    .Columns(2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
    LstRow_Yes = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'last row in filtered column

    If LstRow_Yes > 0 Then
        Set rngFilter_Yes2 = rngFilter_Yes
    ElseIf LstRow_Yes = 0 Then 'No yes's in the column
        ReDim Preserve ProdWith(1 To 2)
        ProdWith(1) = WS_Sel.Cells(v + 1, 1).Value 
        ProdWith(2) = "No products"
        With WS_Prods_With
            .Range(.Cells(z - 2, 1), .Cells(z - 2, 2)) = ProdWith 
        End With
        GoTo NoCells 'skip the rest of the code
    End If
 End With

    For Each cel In rngFilter_Yes2 'check filtered column for yes's! Add to appropriate counter
        Select Case cel
            Case Is = "~"
            Case Is = "RA": RA_counter = RA_counter + 1
            Case Is = "Comp": CP_counter = CP_counter + 1
        End Select
    Next cel

Total = CP_counter + RA_counter

  For v = 1 To Total                 
        counter = counter + 1
        ReDim Preserve ProdWith(1 To counter)
        ProdWith(v) = WS_Sel.Cells(v + 1, 1).Value
  Next v
```

Comment: Need to see much more code than that to help you

Comment: What else do you need to see? How I filtered?

Comment: Yes, and how that is related to this code

Comment: Towards the end: `WS_Sel.Cells(v + 1, 1)` will ignore cells' visibility and give you whatever is at that location, hidden or not. So if v=4 and you execute that code, you'll get Cells(5, 1) aka "A5", even if "A5" and others are hidden. Is there any reason you can't just build your ProdWith array inside the other loop? You already have the values of only the visible cells using 'cel' so all you'd have to do is keep throwing 'cel' into the end of your array. No need to separate the task into two loops.